# MediaPlayer error (100, 0) when playing mp3 stream on Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, samsung-mobile

I have application which is playing mp3 stream, today I've faced that streaming doesn't work on `Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini`. I've also tested application on 'Samsung Galaxy S4' and some other `Samsung` phones and it worked correctly. So `Galaxy S4 Mini` for now is the only model with this problem which I was able to found. 
The code is like that:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://icecast.omroep.nl:80/radio1-sb-mp3");

mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

I receive `E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)` after `prepareAsync()`. I've spend few hours playing with different `setDataSource` and creating `MediaPlayer` methods - no one helped. I've also investigated this solution: http://www.piterwilson.com/blog/2014/03/15/mediacodec-mediaextractor-and-audiotrack-to-the-rescue/ but it didn't help either. 
In the same time playing mp3 files from external storage works perfectly, but I really need to stream it. 
 
This looks like known samsung issue, does anyone have working solution? 
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed by Samsung in latest software update.